# Why new js Fetch standard forbid response header name as 'Set Cookie 1 / 2'?

Tags: javascript, standards, fetch-api

I'm very surpised that https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/ standard doesn't allow to set cookie from server. I expected New Fetch will be awesome alternative of XHR thing, but...

Does anybody knows any official answer for it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you state is incorrect. The server can definitely set cookies, but as with XMLHttpRequest you cannot access them from the API. The only way to observe cookies from JavaScript is `document.cookies` and we decided not to increase the number of places since we haven't found a good way to do that, while also respecting cookie flags such as `HttpOnly`.

Comment: Is what you say about server setting cookies with `fetch` confirmed?  I just tried in Chrome version 46 and it didn't set cookies when using `fetch`, even though `Set-Cookie` header was in the response.  I switched to `XMLHttpRequest` and made a request to the same URL and cookies were set.

Comment: You need to set the credentials mode appropriately for the server to be able to set cookies.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how the credential mode can be set appropriately?

Comment: E.g., `fetch("...", {credentials:"same-origin"})` for XMLHttpRequest's default behavior or `fetch("...", {credentials:"include"})` if you want XMLHttpRequest's behavior with `withCredentials` being set to true.